# Python Beam can't pickle/dill a large Tensorflow Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-dataflow, tensorflow-serving

We are attempting to serve an image processing model (in Tensorflow) in-line so that we don't have to make external calls to REST service, or to a Cloud-ML/ML-Engine model due to speed purposes.

Rather than attempting to load the model at every inference, we wanted to test whether or not we could just load the model into memory for each instance of the beam.DoFn object, that way we can cut down the loading and serving time for the model.

e.g.

```
    from __future__ import absolute_import
    from __future__ import division
    from __future__ import print_function

    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np


    class InferenceFn(object):

      def __init__(self, model_full_path,):
        super(InferenceFn, self).__init__()
        self.model_full_path = model_full_path
        self.graph = None
        self.create_graph()


      def create_graph(self):
        if not tf.gfile.FastGFile(self.model_full_path):
          self.download_model_file()
        with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
          with tf.gfile.FastGFile(self.model_full_path, 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
            _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
        self.graph = graph
```

This is able run locally just fine when its not a beam.DoFn and just a regular class, but when its converted over to a DoFn and I try to execute it remotely with Cloud Dataflow, the job fails because during serialization/pickling, i want to believe that its attempting to serialize the whole model

e.g. 
[Example of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVHDA.png)

Is there a way to circumvent this or prevent python/dataflow from attempting to serialize the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- storing the model as a field on the DoFn requires it to be serialized in order to get that code onto each worker. You should look at the following:

1. Arrange to have the model file available on each worker. This is described for Dataflow in the [Python dependencies document](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dependencies-python#non-python-dependencies).
2. In your DoFn implement the `start_bundle` method and have it read the file and store it in a thread local.

This ensures the contents of the file isn't read on your local machine and pickled, but instead the file is made available to each worker and then read in.

Comment: The start_bundle function worked. The issue was with the depth of the model file that we were trying to serve up.